# Convert a character variable into a logical expression in order to use it later inside the subset argument of the subset() function

Tags: r, subset, boolean-expression

I'm trying to convert a character variable into a logical expression in order to use it later inside the subset argument of the subset() function, and all of this is inside a bigger function called early_prep() I created. The problem is when I execute

```
early_prep(file_name = "n44.txt", keep_rows = "block > 1")
```

it  deletes all rows in my raw_data data frame instead of deleting only those in which block > 1.

Bellow is the relevant part of the `early_prep()` function:

```
early_prep <- function(file_name,keep_rows = FALSE){

  read_data <- function(file_name){
  extension <- substr(file_name, nchar(file_name) - 3, nchar(file_name))
  if (extension == ".txt"){
    raw_data <<- read.table(file_name, header = TRUE)
    # Print to console
    print("#### Reading txt file ####", quote = FALSE)
  } else if (extension == ".csv"){
    raw_data <<- read.csv(file_name, header = TRUE)
    # Print to console 
    print("#### Reading csv file ####", quote = FALSE)
  } else {
    # Stops running the function
    stop("#### file_name should end with txt or csv extension ####", quote = FALSE)     
  }
 }


  read_data(file_name)

  if (keep_rows != FALSE) {
   keep_rows <- as.logical(keep_rows)
   raw_data <<- subset(raw_data,  keep_rows)
   # Print to console
   print("#### Deleting unnecessary rows in raw_data ####", quote = FALSE)
  }
}
```

Comment: Why not call it as: `early_prep(file_name = "n44.txt", keep_rows = block > 1)`. That's how `subset`'s 'subset' argument is used and how all the regression functions get called when they have expressions passed to their 'subset'-arguments. However, you are advised in `subset` that it is a convenience function not designed for use inside functions. You would not want to do the prior `as.logical(keep_rows)` evaluation because the expression would not have the proper environment. That is what `subset` is supposed to provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
subset(raw_data,eval(parse(text=keep_rows)))
```

Test :

```
keep_rows <- "Blok>1"
raw_data<- data.frame(Blok=c(1,2,3,0))
subset(raw_data,eval(parse(text=keep_rows)))

  Blok
2    2
3    3
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However I tried this inside my early_prerp() function and this time it doesn't delete all rows in my raw_data data frame but it keeps all rows and doesn't delete the ones according to keep_rows     ` if (keep_rows !=   FALSE) {
        #keep_rows <- as.logical(keep_rows)
        #raw_data <<- subset(raw_data, keep_rows)
       subset(raw_data,eval(parse(text = keep_rows)))
        # Print to console
        print("#### Deleting unnecesarry rows in raw_data ####", quote = FALSE)
      }`

Comment: You should reaplce the 2 lines ` keep_rows <- as.logical(keep_rows);
   raw_data <<- subset(raw_data,  keep_rows)`  by my code.

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what I did and now it keeps all rows and doesn't delete rows in which block > 1

Comment: @ayalaall This shouls work . Don't use global `<<-` operator. Just assign `<-` and don't forget to return a result in the end of your function...

Comment: Hey again. I have the same question but with the select argument of subset(). I tried what you offered with the select argument and it doesn't work: When I try to pass a string vector to the `early_prep(file_name = "n44.txt", keep_col = c("soa", "congruency"))` function and then use it within subset: `raw_data <- subset(raw_data, select = keep_col)` I get a warning message saying: "the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used". Does anyone have an idea about what I can do? Thanks!

Comment: @ayalaall please avoid asking questions in the comment. Better to ask a new question.